# Home up button highlights after hiding EditText in Android

Tags: android

[image]

The problem is that when I click the back button when introducing text in an EditText, suddenly the Home Up button gets selected in a darker color.

I've disabled the Home Up button and it continues happening. What can I do?

---

Well, I've made some improvements forcing to focus on an element on my layout. But the up navigation button keeps getting the focus after the EditText. The action happens like this:

1. I hide the EditText that has the focus
2. The up navigation button (Android robot) gets the focus
3. My layout element gets the focus

How can I solve that?

Comment: What is "Home Up button" ? How does it change, paste an illustration or some screen shots.

Comment: The button from the actionbar that makes the navigation backwards.

Comment: Whithout the code and/or some screens I can not help.

Comment: Screen added to see what I mean

Comment: Do you set it selected at some point in the code ? How is the selecting controlled in the code? Can't you override the `onBackPressed()` method to unselect it on the Back button press (with a check if it has been selected) ?

Comment: I've been making some checkings and if I don't introduce text in the EditText that I want to hide, that "misterious selection" doesn't happen. But if I introduce some text and then hide it, the "misterious selection" happens

Comment: This might be due to the shift of the `<requestFocus>` to this "Home Up", you can play a little with it and see if it's not shifted towards if, when you press back.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved!

It was a problem of the keyboard of the emulator =S

I had the option to get input from my laptop keyboard, I've disabled it and now it works

Thanks to g00dy for the help =)